# Game Lives Counter

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a basic video game based on answers! If you get the right answer, you go to the next level(form), if you are wrong you get to the next level but you lose a life. Basically, I have a label that has the number "3" as a .Text parameter, I store the labelLifes.text in an integer so I can work with it. If you press the wrong button, integer goes integer--; But the problem is that when the next level(form) shows up, I try to get that integer value so I can display it on my new form, it says 3 even if I choose the wrong answer. I've tested it, in the first from it goes to 2, 1 and eventually 0 but in the next form the numbers resets to 3. Why is that?

Level1

```
> public void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             //wrong answer -1 soul
>             Thread.Sleep(200);
>             score--;
>             labelSouls.Text = score.ToString();
> 
>             Level2 l2 = new Level2();
>             l2.ShowDialog();
>             Hide();
>         }
> 
>         public void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
> 
>             //right answer
>             Thread.Sleep(200);
>             Level2 l2 = new Level2();
>             l2.ShowDialog();
>             Hide();
> 
>         }
> 
>         public void label1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             //wrong answer -1 soul
>             Thread.Sleep(200);
>             score--;
>             labelSouls.Text = score.ToString();
> 
>             Level2 l2 = new Level2();
>             l2.ShowDialog();
>             Hide();
```

Level 2

```
private void Level2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Level1 l1 = new Level1();
            score2 = l1.score;
            label2.Text = score2.ToString();
            label1.Hide();
            label2.Hide();
            textLVL2 = labelLVL2.Text;
            len3 = textLVL2.Length;
            labelLVL2.Text = "";
            timer1.Start();
            player.Play();         
        }
```

Comment: Remember that when you create a `new` object it's a separate instance and has its own instances of local variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how your original level 1 is initialised, however it would appear that the line `score2 = l1.score;` is getting the default score value, which is three. The reason for this is the previous line where you have `Level1 l1 = new Level1();`. This will set l1 to a *new* Level1, not the Level1 that the user just completed. In order to set it to the current Level1 you'd have to pass it in as a parameter or similar instead of creating a new one, or alternatively you could make Level1.score a static variable.